# Found 'CPU is high' in Oracle's trc log file, but CPU usage is less than 25% indeed

Tags: oracle

There is an Oracle 11g RAC database in our system.
The server has 2 E5-2403 CPUs and a total of 8 cores.
There is the config in the database:

num_cpu: 8
num_cpu_cores: 3
num_cpu_sockets: 1
sessions_current: 88
sessions_highwater: 112

---

I hound this log in the orcl_lmhb_xxxx.trc file:

```
*** 2022-11-13 03:45:09.811
kjgcr_SlaveReqBegin: message queued to slave
kjgcr_Main: KJGCR_ACTION - id 3
CPU is high.  Top oracle users listed below:
     Session           Serial         CPU
     420                 1             3
     361                 3             2
     178                25             0
       5                 5             0
      60                 1             0

*** 2022-11-13 03:45:14.844
kjgcr_Main: Reset called for action high cpu, identify users, count 0

*** 2022-11-13 03:45:14.844
kjgcr_Main: Reset called for action high cpu, kill users, count 0

*** 2022-11-13 03:45:14.844
kjgcr_Main: Reset called for action high cpu, activate RM plan, count 0

*** 2022-11-13 03:45:14.844
kjgcr_Main: Reset called for action high cpu, set BG into RT, count 0

*** 2022-11-13 03:45:29.845
kjgcr_Main: KJGCR_ACTION - id 5

*** 2022-11-13 03:45:49.846
==============================
LMS0 (ospid: 4072) has not moved for 82 sec (1668282349.1668282267)
kjfmGCR_HBCheckAll: LMS0 (ospid: 4072) has status 2
  : waiting for event 'gcs remote message' for 0 secs with wait_id 6651.
  ===[ Wait Chain ]===
  Wait chain is empty.

*** 2022-11-13 03:45:49.846
==============================
LMS1 (ospid: 4456) has not moved for 82 sec (1668282349.1668282267)
kjfmGCR_HBCheckAll: LMS1 (ospid: 4456) has status 2
  : waiting for event 'gcs remote message' for 0 secs with wait_id 6785.
  ===[ Wait Chain ]===
  Wait chain is empty.
kjgcr_Main: KJGCR_ACTION - id 5
```

I want to fix these warnings. If I set 'num_cpu_sockets' to 2, could Oracle use more cores CPU or not? Any other suggestions?

Thanks very much.

Here is more information about my database.

```
show parameters cpu;
NAME                                     TYPE       VALUE 
-------------------------------          -------    ----- 
cpu_count                                integer    8     
parallel_threads_per_cpu                 integer    2     
resource_manager_cpu_allocation          integer    8

select * from v$osstat where stat_name like '%CPU%';

NUM_CPUS                8
RSRC_MGR_CPU_WAIT_TIME  4091
NUM_CPU_CORES           3
NUM_CPU_SOCKETS         1

show parameters resource_manager_plan;
NAME                  TYPE   VALUE 
--------------------- ------ ----- 
resource_manager_plan string       

select * from v$license;
Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
"CORE   11.2.0.3.0  Production"
TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
```

Answer (score 0):

`num_cpu_sockets` is not a parameter you can set. Limiting CPU usage (aka "instance caging") is controlled entirely by the `cpu_count` parameter, which appears to be set to 3, though you should confirm that.

The only reason to limit the number of CPU cores available to an instance is to keep it from competing with other instances for resources on the same host. Multiple *instances* running on the same host in RAC 11g is always a bad idea unless you're dealing with RAC One Node. Sooner or later one instance *will* choke out the others over some system resource, since most can't be caged.

In your case, the instance doesn't have enough CPU available to manage the global cache for the cluster, which is passing data blocks/ownership back and forth between nodes. Assuming only one instance per RAC node, I would increase `cpu_count` to the maximum of 8, which it should default to if not forced.

```
alter system set cpu_count=8 scope=both;
```

or

```
alter system reset cpu_count scope=both;
```

You may need to repeat this on each RAC node/instance to ensure all instances are set the same without a restart.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The way I see it, the CPU_COUNT was set to 8 correctly. NUM_CPU_CORES is incorrect because of Oracle Bug 16007191.